# Set cover: To show the number of minimum coverable combination of the power set of universe $U$ is less than $2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Given a set $U=\{1,2,...,n\}$, and its power set $\mathcal S=\{S_1,...,S_{2^n-1}\}$(without emptyset $\emptyset$), a minimum coverable combination is $S_i\cup...\cup S_k=U$ and $S_i,...,S_k$ are pairwise disjoint.

For example, when $U=\{1,2,3\}$, then $\mathcal S=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and a minimum coverable combination is $S_4=\{1,2\}$ and $S_3=\{3\}$ then $S_4\cup S_3=U$ and $S_4\cap S_3=\emptyset$.(don't count the permutations so $S_4\cup S_3$ is considered the same as $S_3\cup S_4$)

Now the question is to prove the number of minimum coverable combination of $U$ is less than or equal to $2^n$

Comment: To clarify the definitions: is $S_1 = \{ 1, 2 \}, S_2 = \{ 1, 3 \}, S_3 = \{ 2, 3 \}$ a minimum coverable combination of $U = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$? Is it a minimum coverable combination if we remove $S_3$?

Comment: No, because $S_1\cap S_2 \neq \emptyset$ and $S_1\cap S_3 \neq \emptyset$ and $S_2\cap S_3 \neq \emptyset$ so all of each combination is not a minimum combination. $S_1=\{1\},S_2=\{2\},S_3=\{3\}$ and $S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3$ is a minimum combination because $S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3=\emptyset$ @Adayah

Comment: But in my example $S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 = \emptyset$ too. If you don't want my example to be a minimum coverable combination, then probably instead of the condition $S_1 \cap \ldots \cap S_k = \emptyset$ you mean that $S_1, \ldots, S_k$ are **pairwise** disjoint, i.e. $S_i \cap S_j = \emptyset$ whenever $i \neq j$? Note: a family $\{ S_1, \ldots, S_k \}$ of pairwise disjoint sets such that $S_1 \cup \ldots S_k = U$ is called a partition of $U$ - it's a widely used terminology.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that $S_1,...,S_k $ are pairwise disjiont, its my bad.@Adayah

Comment: So finally, are you asking to prove that the number of all partitions of $U$ is $\leqslant 2^n$? ;-)

Comment: I don't know about partitions problem but is it means that $U$ is actually $\leqslant 2^n$? @Adayah

Comment: Are the sets $S_i$ allowed to be the empty set?  If so, there are infinitely many minimum coverable combinations simply by adding any number of empty set.  And I suppose that you don't count permutations of $S_i$'s right?  (Like, $\big(S_1,S_2\big)=\big(\{1\},\{2,3\}\big)$ is considered the same as $\big(S_1,S_2\big)=\big(\{2,3\},\{1\}\big)$.)

Comment: Sorry, so now let $S_i \neq \emptyset$ and I don't count permutations of $S_i$ @Batominovski

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$. Here are some minimum coverable combinations of $U$:

$\begin{align*}
1. \: & \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \} \\
2. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 2, 3, 4, 5 \} \\
3. \: & \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 3, 4, 5 \} \\
4. \: & \{ 3 \}, \{ 1, 2, 4, 5 \} \\
5. \: & \{ 4 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3, 5 \} \\
6. \: & \{ 5 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \} \\
7. \: & \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 3, 4, 5 \} \\
8. \: & \{ 1, 3 \}, \{ 2, 4, 5 \} \\
9. \: & \{ 1, 4 \}, \{ 2, 3, 5 \} \\
10. \: & \{ 1, 5 \}, \{ 2, 3, 4 \} \\
11. \: & \{ 2, 3 \}, \{ 1, 4, 5 \} \\
12. \: & \{ 2, 4 \}, \{ 1, 3, 5 \} \\
13. \: & \{ 2, 5 \}, \{ 1, 3, 4 \} \\
14. \: & \{ 3, 4 \}, \{ 1, 2, 5 \} \\
15. \: & \{ 3, 5 \}, \{ 1, 2, 4 \} \\
16. \: & \{ 4, 5 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \\
17. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 3, 4, 5 \} \\
18. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 3 \}, \{ 2, 4, 5 \} \\
19. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 4 \}, \{ 2, 3, 5 \} \\
20. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 5 \}, \{ 2, 3, 4 \} \\
21. \: & \{ 2 \}, \{ 3 \}, \{ 1, 4, 5 \} \\
22. \: & \{ 2 \}, \{ 4 \}, \{ 1, 3, 5 \} \\
23. \: & \{ 2 \}, \{ 5 \}, \{ 1, 3, 4 \} \\
24. \: & \{ 3 \}, \{ 4 \}, \{ 1, 2, 5 \} \\
25. \: & \{ 3 \}, \{ 5 \}, \{ 1, 2, 4 \} \\
26. \: & \{ 4 \}, \{ 5 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \\
27. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 2, 3 \}, \{ 4, 5 \}  \\
28. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 2, 4 \}, \{ 3, 5 \}  \\
29. \: & \{ 1 \}, \{ 2, 5 \}, \{ 3, 4 \}  \\
30. \: & \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, \{ 4, 5 \}  \\
31. \: & \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 4 \}, \{ 3, 5 \}  \\
32. \: & \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 5 \}, \{ 3, 4 \}  \\
33. \: & \{ 3 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 4, 5 \}  \\
34. \: & \{ 3 \}, \{ 1, 4 \}, \{ 2, 5 \}  \\
35. \: & \{ 3 \}, \{ 1, 5 \}, \{ 2, 4 \}  \\
36. \: & \{ 4 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 3, 5 \}  \\
37. \: & \{ 4 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, \{ 2, 5 \}  \\
38. \: & \{ 4 \}, \{ 1, 5 \}, \{ 2, 3 \}  \\
39. \: & \{ 5 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 3, 4 \}  \\
40. \: & \{ 5 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, \{ 2, 4 \}  \\
41. \: & \{ 5 \}, \{ 1, 4 \}, \{ 2, 3 \}  \\
\end{align*}$

There are more than $2^5 = 32$, so the claim is false.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still have another question: if the question change to  ‘is in $O(2^n)$’,will it be true?

Comment: You missed $11$ more partitions: $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $\{1,2,3,45\}$, $\{1,2,4,35\}$, $\{1,2,5,34\}$, $\{1,3,4,25\}$, $\{1,3,5,24\}$, $\{1,4,5,23\}$, $\{2,3,4,15\}$, $\{2,3,5,14\}$, $\{2,4,5,13\}$, and $\{3,4,5,12\}$.

Comment: @Batominovski I wrote "some partitions", not "all partitions". The reason for that is I was too lazy to continue past 41st (at that point a pattern ended)...

Comment: @wst That question is beyond my counting skills, but Batominovski's excellent answer gives a good approximation which implies that the answer is also negative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_n$ denote the number of partitions of the set $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  This is known as the $n$-th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).  The first few values are $B_0=1$, $B_1=1$, $B_2=2$, $B_3=5$, $B_4=15$, and $B_5=52$.  It can be shown that
$$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,B_k\text{ and }B_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right\}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, where
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right\}=\frac{1}{k!}\,\sum_{j=0}^k\,(-1)^{k-j}\,\binom{k}{j}\,j^n$$
is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

It is known that
$$B_n \approx n^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,\exp\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}-n-1\right)\,,$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert $W$-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).  That is, using $W(n)\approx \ln(n)$, we get that 
$$B_n > \left(\frac{n}{\text{e}\,\ln(n)}\right)^n$$
for every positive integer $n$.  Therefore, $B_n$ grows much faster than $2^n$.